# 'OpenSSL NOT found' on raspberry pi 4, I don't know how to deal with this situation

Tags: terminal

First of all I have used

```
sudo apt install git build-essential cmake libuv1-dev libhwloc-dev -y
```

Everything went fine in this.

I am getting following error on my raspberry pi terminal

I used

```
git clone https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig.git
```

and when I used

```
cmake ..
```

I got the following thing.

```
Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error at cmake/OpenSSL.cmake:47 (message):
```

[image: terminal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing `libssl-dev` and running `cmake` again. Or, as your error log says, build with `cmake -DWITH_TLS=OFF` if you don't need the crypto features.

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved my issue.